# PHP Moving mySQL Tree Node

Tags: php, mysql, tree, nodes

I am having trouble trying to move sub nodes or parent nodes up or down... not that good at math.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (   `page-id` mediumint(8) unsigned
> ```
>
> NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `page-left`
>   mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   `page-right` smallint(8) unsigned NOT
>   NULL,   `page-title` text NOT NULL,
>   `page-content` text NOT NULL,
>   `page-time` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   `page-slug` text NOT NULL,
>   `page-template` text NOT NULL,
>   `page-parent` mediumint(8) unsigned
>   NOT NULL,   `page-type` text NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`page-id`) )
>   ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
>   ;
>
> INSERT INTO `pages` (`page-id`,
>   `page-left`, `page-right`,
>   `page-title`, `page-content`,
>   `page-time`, `page-slug`,
>   `page-template`, `page-parent`,
>   `page-type`) VALUES (17, 1, 6, '1',
>   '', 0, 'PARENT', '', 0, ''), (18, 2,
>   5, '2', '', 0, 'SUB', '', 17, ''),
>   (19, 3, 4, '3', '', 0, 'SUB-SUB', '',
>   18, ''), (20, 7, 8, '5', '', 0,
>   'TEST', '', 0, '');

As example how would I move TEST up above PARENT and say move SUB down below SUB-SUB by playing with the page-left/page-right IDs? Code is not required just help with the SQL concept or math for it, would help me understand how to move it better...

Comment: I'd start with formatting that horrible block of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically you want to convert an adjacency list to a nested set? First update your adjacency list (ie. update the page_parent values to the correct values for your new tree), then run the conversion below.

Using PHP (basic code, untested) :

```
class Tree
{    
    private $count = 0;
    private $data = array();

    /**
     * Rebuild nested set
     * 
     * @param $rawData array Raw tree data
     */
    public function rebuild($rawData)
    {
        $this->data = $rawData;
        $this->count = 1;
        $this->traverse(0);        
    }

    private function traverse($id)
    {
        $lft = $this->count;
        $this->count++;

        if (isset($this->data[$id])) {
            $kid = $this->data[$id];
            if ($kid) {
                foreach ($kid as $c) {
                    $this->traverse($c);
                }
            }
        }

        $rgt = $this->count;
        $this->count++;

        // TODO: Update left and right values to $lft & $rgt in your DB for page_id $id
        ...
    }
}
```

When you call this, $rawData should contain an array of ID's, indexed by parent-id, you could create it (based on your table structure) as follows ($db should contain an active PDO connection object):

```
    $sql = 'SELECT page_id, page_parent FROM pages ORDER BY page_parent';

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $rawData = array();
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $parent = $row['page_parent'];
        $child = $row['page_id'];
        if (!array_key_exists($parent, $rawData)) {
            $rawData[$parent] = array();
        }
        $rawData[$parent][] = $child;
    }
```

To do the conversion you would need something like :

```
$tree = new Tree();
$tree->rebuild($rawData);
```

So basically you create an array that is containing all nodes in your tree indexed by parent which will be traversed in a recursive manner to determine the correct left and right values per node.

BTW You could do it in plain SQL (after you adapt table/column names) :
http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/638123-regenerate-nested-set-using-parent_id-structure