# How to sort MySQL query by two columns

Tags: php, mysql

The following is my DB data, how can I sorting it by sid and prev_sid with php/mysql!?

```
sid prev_sid    type
000 197         app_home    
197 198         page_teach  
198 218         page_teach  
199 211         page_step   
211 207         link        
218 559         page_step   
559 199         page_step
```

Result:

```
sid prev_sid    type
000 197         app_home
197 198         page_teach
198 218         page_teach
218 559         page_step
559 199         page_step
199 211         page_step
211 207         link
```

000 --> 197 --> 198 --> 218 --> 559 --> 199 --> 199 --> 211 --> 207

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you reconsider your table design. This type of data representation prevents the rows from being sorted conveniently and efficiently.

If you need to keep the current table design, I suspect that you will need to involve SQL variables, and that the sorting select becomes quite messy and probably not efficient.

Another, possibly better solution, would be to do the sorting on the application side, at which point it could easily be done in linear time using a hash-map, mapping sid-values to pairs of prev_sid and type values.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is an adjacency list (i.e. sed and prev_sid define a recursive parent-child relationship). If this is the case, then to get the items in order you could convert it to a nested set and sort by the left value of every node to get the items in order. For more information on hierarchical data refer to [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

BTW, if you want to convert an adjacency list to a nested set using PHP check out my answer at [PHP Moving mySQL Tree Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432725/php-moving-mysql-tree-node/2433013#2433013).

Comment: what do you mean by "sort by the left value of every node"?

Comment: If you take the time to look at the link I provided about hierarchical data, and scroll to the description of nested sets, you'll see what it is. A node is a record in the tree.

Answer (score -1):

If you look carefully at your data, you will see that you only need to sort by `sid`. This is done in SQL by appending `ORDER BY sid` to your query.

```
SELECT sid, prev_sid, type FROM table ORDER BY sid
```

If you need to sort on two columns (which is not the case here but it might be useful), `ORDER BY` can take a list of columns as parameter.

```
SELECT sid, prev_sid, type FROM table ORDER BY sid, prev_sid
```

Comment: No, if you look carefully at the OPs example output you'll note that sid:559 should come before sid:199. (S)He wants an ordering where the sid of each row is equal to the prev_sid of the preceding row.

Answer (score -2):

> 218 > 559 > 199

Not using any numbering system I've ever used it's not. I don't think you've explained your problem very well.

Looking at the example I suspect you want to sort based on either the value for sid or the value for perv_sid, depending on which is the lesser, so:

ORDER BY LEAST(sid, prev_sid)

C.

Comment: As mentioned in other comments: He wants an ordering where the sid of each row is equal to the prev_sid of the preceding row.  You should not interpret ">" as numerical "greater than". You, with 2000+ rep could perhaps change it to "-->" (or something) to clarify this.